# How does pipeline work for nlp tasks and what do the accuracy scores imply

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, random-forest, text-classification, bert-language-model

[First I would like to thank the community of SO; for whose support I could actually finish making an end to end data science project (including deployment.)]

Over to my question.

I wanted to create an app that will predict success or failure depending upon textual input data.

In order to construct the model; instead of developing an algorithm from scratch; I used existing algorithms instead.

While training my dataframe [which is a textual corpus]; I frequently wrote:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(
[
    ("vect", CountVectorizer()),
    ("tfidf", TfidfTransformer()),
    ("clf", my_chosen_model()),
]
)
```

That is because I saw several code examples doing so. I however, didn't clearly understand the usage of pipeline. Can anyone please explain it (or share any link which can help people like me from non-programming backgrounds understand it better.)

After completing my experiments I obtained accuracy scores on text data:

```
RandomForest    SVM    MLP    MultinomialNB
0.80            0.85   0.86    0.80
```

When I increased the number of data (from initial 20000 to 50000), accuracy scores were:

```
RandomForest    SVM    MLP    MultinomialNB
0.85            0.85   0.87    0.82
```

I also tried BERT; which gave an accuracy of : 0.72 on text data.

Can someone please explain to me here:

1. Why BERT performed so low - despite that BERT is preferred by many. I followed the exact steps as mentioned here for my task: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/07/transfer-learning-for-nlp-fine-tuning-bert-for-text-classification/
2. What do the accuracy scores imply about different algorithms in regards to data? And will it be wise to choose either MLP / SVM or choose Random forest due to a jump in performance.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask this kind of non-programming question. There are many things to comment on here, but the first one that comes to mind is that you should probably use the mindf parameter in CountVectorizer to remove rare words. Accuracy is simply the percentage of correct predicitions in the test set, it's usually better to use precision/recall/f-score to get a clearer picture of what happens. About BERT it can depend on many things, starting with the size of the training set.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to this resource, and also your answer.